# Выход/удаление родительской функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

При уводе курсора за границы экрана показывается попап, но только 1 раз. Подскажите адекватный способ как сделать не говнокодно) Пробую хранить переменную в `localStorage` и проверяю показывать/не показывать попап. Но сейчас есть проблема при первом заходе, после показа попапа нужно как-то убить ф-ю `mousemove` иначе попап выскакивает каждый раз при уводе курсора

```
let showedShares = localStorage.getItem('share') || {};

let sharesTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if(e.pageY <= window.scrollY + 2){
            popup(1);
            localStorage.setItem('share', "don't show share")
        }
    })
}, 1000)

if (showedShares === "don't show share") {
    clearTimeout(sharesTimeout) //Если человек видел попап, то обнуляю ф-ю интервала
}
```

Comment: Зачем здесь `setTimeout`?

Comment: Не знаю, первая мысль, которая пришла в голову.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(localStorage.getItem('share') != "don't show share") {
  function sharePopup(e) {
    if (e.pageY <= window.scrollY + 2){
        popup(1);
        localStorage.setItem('share', "don't show share");
        $(document).off("mousemove", sharePopup);
    }
  }
  $(document).on("mousemove", sharePopup);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то котелок не варит уже

Comment: А нельзя проверить значение localStorage и если показывать попап не нужно, то обнулить mouseMove? А то она так всегда работает, не очень айс)